# How tell if root category exists or is defined via database in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, database, category

I have access to a database in a dev environment for Magento EE 2.1.7. I'm currently not seeing any categories on the frontend and I get a very strange "too many redirects" error when I attempt to navigate to Catalog > Categories within the admin.

Put simply: I have a suspicion that the client accidentally deleted the root category from the database but I can't view categories with any GUI to determine this. Is there a way to determine if a root category exists or is defined via the database?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. To see configured root category for any store from the database, just run the following:

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'catalog/category/root_id';
```

Turns out you can technically see it from one other location in Magento's admin by going to Stores -> All Stores - [Choose Store].

Hope this helps someone else.